# How to factor a matrix to a product of kernel matrices?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, linear-algebra

Problem statement:

> Say we have a set of kernel square matrices = {K1, K2, .., Kn}. Given
>   a matrix A find the product involving the least amount of matrix
>   multiplications which gives: A = Ki * Kj * ... * Kz

Example:

```
Say we have these two matrices in the set of Kernel matrices:
K1 = (1 2)    K2 = (5 6)
     (3 4)         (7 8)

Then we have a solution for A=K1*K2=(19 22) and also for B=K1*K1*K2=(105 122)
                                    (43 50)                         (229 266)
```

Is there any existing C or C++ library which I can use to find the solution? If not, is there any known algorithm/heuristics?

P.S. this is not a homework question or a theoretical question or some other trolly thing. This is a real problem I need to solve for a side project I am working on at my day job.

Comment: What is the typical number and dimensions of the kernel matrices? Is there a upper limit on the number of times a certain kernel can appear in the product? Is a brute-force attitude feasible?

Comment: Are you trying to work out the set of K matrices required to make a given A matrix?

Comment: @ItamarKatz Upper limit is 16x16. There is no limit on the number of appearances, but let's say that the Basis usually give a good coverage, so I would not expect many occurances. Brute-force? Only if there is no faster algorithm

Comment: @Skizz Sorry I don't understand

Comment: @Skizz - he is trying to find the decomposition with the least number of matrix multiplications. All kernels are known.

Comment: Sub-problem of this is to decide whether a matrix A can or cannot be represented as matrix multiplication of the kernel matrices. Or are you given a matrix that is confirmed to be "factorize-able"?

Comment: @nhahtdh For simplicity, let's assume such a multiplication always exists

Comment: It seems to me that this is quite a specific problem, so I doubt you could find an existing library to solve it. In looking for all possible decompositions, I think you could use a dynamic programming approach in order to reduce the complexity.

Comment: Interesting question... I think it'd be more appropriate for and/or you might get better answers from a place like http://math.stackexchange.com/ for example, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the trace and determinant of the matrix.  Since trace and determinant of a product can be computed more efficiently than a full multiplication, they may help you rule out combinations efficiently.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Multiplicativity_and_matrix_groups

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a tool to do matrix operations. Eigen may be suit for you. **http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page**

Comment: It seems to support only some special cases, but not what I need: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html

Answer (score 0):

The idea of trace for reducing combinations is good, except that tr(A*B) is not equal to tr(A)*tr(B), so you have to use determinant instead det(A*B)=det(A)*det(B).

An integer factorisation of det(M) might help you reducing the combinatorial, unless your kernel has some det(Ki)=+/-1...